# How to check ™ using java code

Tags: java

How to check ™ using java code.As enter ™ on the textbox.I am getting the value as "".Please help me...

Note:Actually i want a special character check so ™ is in special character list.So when I ™ in textbox.And When retrive the value in Java i am getting space only.hw to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

You need the character's Unicode and then you can use the following escape sequence inside of a String: `"\u2122"`. That should equal `"™"`, which is not possible.